# PhpTus integration in symfony2 website

Tags: symfony, file-upload, upload

I try to use Tus.IO but it’s complicated to debug.

[http://tus.io/](https://github.com/leblanc-simon/php-tus)

I would integrate php-tus server in my website made with Symfony2.8 / Apache2.4 / PHP5.6 in FPM mode.

1. Here is my apache vhost (My website in not on root, but on /upload subfolder):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

      #  DocumentRoot /var/www/hebergementbcdi_upload/web
      Alias /upload /var/www/hebergementbcdi_upload/web

      <Directory "/var/www/hebergementbcdi_upload/web">
         <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
          <Files ~ (\.php$)> 
             SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
           </Files>
         </IfModule>

          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://10.133.169.137
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"

          AllowOverride All
          Allow from All

          Options -Includes -ExecCGI
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. I’ve deployed PhpTus in vendor folder via composer.
3. I’ve configured routing.yml like below

   upload_tus_io:
   path:   /hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus
   defaults: { _controller: UploadBcdiBundle:Upload:uploadTusIO }
4. I’ve created controller like this

   ```
    * Url : /hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus
    *
    * @param       Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request                $request                        Requête http en cours.
    *
    * @return      Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response               $response                       Réponse http au format JSON
    */
    public function uploadTusIOAction(Request $request) {

           $upload_data_path =  $this->getParameter('upload_data_path');

           // Create and configure server
           $server = new \PhpTus\Server($upload_data_path,
                                                                   '/hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus',
                                                                   array('prefix' => 'php-tus')
          );

           // Run server
           $response = $server->process(true);
   }
   ```

On client, i use tus-upload (Python client) like this :

tus-upload DATA.zip http://10.133.169.138/upload/hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus --chunk-size 256000 --header Authorization 'foo'

But i’ve this error :

> [2017-03-03 16:50:00,551] INFO Creating file endpoint Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/tus-upload", line 11, in
>   
>       load_entry_point('tus.py==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'tus-upload')()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tus.py", line 83, in
>   _cmd_upload
>       metadata=args.metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tus.py", line 162, in create
>       raise TusError("Create failed: %s" % response) tus.TusError: Create failed:

Have you any idead.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've solved my problem without creating .htaccess file to redirect requests.

I've processed like that in routing.yml :

```
# Upload with TUS.io
upload_tus_io:
    path:   /hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus/files/{upload_filename}
    defaults: { _controller: UploadBcdiBundle:Upload:uploadTusIO }
    methods:  ['POST','PATCH']
    requirements:
        upload_filename: "[a-z0-9]*"
```

Then i've used PHP TUS.io client because Python client doesn't work with PHP Backend.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Client.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/Abort.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/BadHeader.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/Curl.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/File.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/Max.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/Request.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-tus/src/PhpTus/Exception/Required.php';

$filename = '/home/admin/DATA.zip';
$endpoint = 'https://<my_ip>/upload/hebergeurs/V1/upload_tus/files/';

$client = new PhpTus\Client();
$client->setFilename($filename);
$client->setEndPoint($endpoint);
$client->upload();
```

Don't forget to hack Client.php to accept self-signed certiticates :

```
// Disable SSL vérification
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Thanks to me.